# How to copy contents of one WebGLRenderTarget to another WebGLRenderTarget

Tags: three.js, webgl

Can someone please show me an example of copying the contents of one WebGLRenderTarget to another? The following don't seem to work:

```
let tex1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
        width,
        height,
        {
            minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
            magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
            format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
            type: THREE.FloatType
        }
    );

let tex2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
        width,
        height,
        {
            minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
            magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
            format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
            type: THREE.FloatType
        }
    );

// assume content is successfully rendered to tex1

renderer.setRenderTarget(tex2);
renderer.clear(); // Clear the render target before copying
tex2.copy(tex1);
);
```

copy() [apparently causes both textures to share the same data in memory](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/20328) which isn't what I want-- I want completely duplicated data in memory. Regardless, tex2 does not render anything when I try to use copy.

How do I simply duplicate `tex1` to a new WebGLRenderTarget `tex2`?